# Word for "transforming a certain form of energy into a useful and desired form"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the act of transforming a certain form of energy into a useful and desired form. It's for a research project in which we are researching the transformation of 
kinetic energy into electrical or chemical energy.

Comment: Not sure if [energy harvesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_harvesting) could fit the bill

Comment: "Useless" energy is undifferentiated heat, that is the kinetic energy in a volume of uniform temperature. Thermodynamics says that this energy cannot be converted into useful work. Perhaps you could sharpen your question.

Comment: Yes, if the energy can be "transformed into a useful form" then it's not useless.

Comment: If you want to "suggest" something different by your research project, try translating or translation of one form into another for use.

Comment: Energy *conversion* is the usual term. If the process results in chemical (potential) energy, *capture* or *recapture* works, since you are talking about storage as well.

Comment: @deadrat Is my edit thermodynamic-proof?

Comment: Alas, nothing is proof against the impending heat-death of the universe, but while we're waiting, your edit is more than sufficient.  Thanks for humoring me for my pedantic response, which apparently was unnecessary since you found an acceptable answer.  Neither *harness* nor *harvest* seems to me to have the requisite sense of transformation, but what's that compared to the inevitable running down of all existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[harness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/harness)**

> Control and make use of (natural resources), especially to produce
>   energy

[Example](https://www.ucsusa.org/clean_energy/our-energy-choices/renewable-energy/how-hydroelectric-energy.html#.V2l3QPkrKUk):

> Today, harnessing the power of moving water to generate electricity,
>   known as hydroelectric power, is the largest source of emissions-free,
>   renewable electricity in the United States and worldwide.

also [Kinetic energy harvesting: Everyday human activity could power the internet of things](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/161079-kinetic-energy-harvesting-everyday-human-activity-could-power-the-internet-of-things):

> Researchers at Columbia University have conducted the first exhaustive
>   study into kinetic energy harvesting — the harvesting of “free” energy
>   from common human activities, such as walking, writing with a pencil,
>   taking a book off a shelf, or opening a door.

Answer (score 0):

transduce, transduced, transducer (n.)

: to convert (something, such as energy or a message) into another form (Merriam Webster)

: a device that converts variations in a physical quantity, such as pressure or brightness, into an electrical signal, or vice versa (Oxford)

For example, microphones and headphones are transducers because they convert acoustic energy into electrical energy and vice versa (note: plugging your headphones into a 1/4" or 1/9" microphone jack turns them into a microphone).